# How to write a plugin that works for both Python3 and python?

Tags: vimscript, vimscript-python

I feel like this might be because of my lack of vimscript knowledge.  Basically I want to write a patch for this plugin https://github.com/actionshrimp/vim-xpath to make it work for python3 (and hence vim8).

I can just change it to say py3 everywhere it currently says py however that breaks it for python2 and so wouldn't be submittable as a pull request.

I don't want to litter the code with if/else `has("python3")` everywhere - ideally I'd like to assign the relevant command to a variable in an if else and then just use it everywhere.  Or something similarly elegant

How do I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See `help pythonx` in Vim 8:

> Because most python code can be written so that it works with python
>   2.6+ and python 3 the pyx* functions and commands have been written.  They work exactly the same as the Python 2 and 3 variants, but select
>   the Python version using the 'pyxversion' setting.

Comment: Does this only support vim8? What if I write a plugin that is compatible with Vim 7?

Comment: @artificerpi I guess you can use has(“python3”) and handle it yourself